# Html Div positioning

Tags: css, html, layout

im trying to get the positioning right on these divs, I would like it so that the banner, div is half the page and to the right of the page so that it covers the same horizontal space that the container does, and to have the menubar div left aligned.

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language">
    <title>hhhh</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="bannerdiv" title="Banner" align="center">

        <img alt="logo" height="63" src="images/Logo.gif" width="126"></div>


    <div id="container">
    <h2 class="auto-style2">tgfdgfdgfghgfhgfh</h2>

        </div>

    <div id="menubar" title="menu" style="width: 13%">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 96px; width: 82%">


    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background-color: #008852;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#menubar

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#EFF1EB;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #638529;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
#mainpage {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color: #EDEFEE;
}
#menubar {
    font-size: xx-small;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="mainpage" class="auto-style1" style="height: 96px; width:   82%;float:right;height:50%;">
```

?

Comment: it's a quizzical answer as I believe it answers the question, however I'm not 100% sure what the question was!

Answer (score 0):

All of your styling should be done through css, not through style, width, height etc

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="image"/>
  </div>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>main content</p>
</div>
```

Your CSS is then

```
#container{
    width:960px;
}
#nav{
    width:240px;
    float:left;
}
#main-content{
    width:720px;
    float:left;
}
```

I would suggest [watching the series at nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/convert-a-warm-cheerful-web-design-to-html-and-css/) about html and css to get an idea of the correct way to use css. Good luck